# MSBuild task does not cause generated c# files to compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I've been trying to write an MSBuild task to "compile" CoCo/R .ATG files into C# files which will then get compiled into the executable, this is to replace the pre-build event.
I've managed to get the .ATG -> .cs process working, however something is not right since the generates .cs files do not get compiled.
If I then modify the .ATG file again, the "old" .cs files seems to get compiled then new ones generated.
I'm quite sure I'm missing something that will inform the rest of the build process that these files have changed.

Here is the target definition that I have included in my Visual Studio 2010 project.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="BuildATG" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CoreBuildDependsOn>
      BuildATGTarget;
      $(CoreBuildDependsOn)
    </CoreBuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BuildATGTarget" Inputs="@(BuildATG)" Outputs="@(BuildATG -> '%(RelativeDir)Parser.cs')">
    <Exec Command="Coco.exe %(BuildATG.Identity)" Outputs="%(BuildATG.RelativeDir)Parser.cs" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

I am completly new to MSBuild, so any advice / pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I have found is to do the following changes and add an ItemGroup inside the target.

```
<Target Name="BuildATGTarget" Inputs="@(BuildATG)" Outputs="@(BuildATG -> '%(RelativeDir)Parser.cs')">
  <Exec Command="Coco.exe %(BuildATG.Identity)" Outputs="%(BuildATG.RelativeDir)Parser.cs" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="%(BuildATG.RelativeDir)Parser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="%(BuildATG.RelativeDir)Scanner.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

To avoid duplicate files in your build, you also need to mark the files (Parser.cs and Scanner.cs) in the Visual Studio 2010 project with **Build Action: None**